# One formula for Hermitian form

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, differential-forms

I am really struggling with this one: I have a two form $T=T_{i\overline{j}}dz_id\overline{z}_j$ and a Hermitian form $\omega=g_{i\overline{j}}dz_i\wedge d\overline{z_j}$. And I want to prove the formula $T\wedge \frac{\omega^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=(g^{\overline{j}k}T_{\overline{k}j})\frac{\omega^n}{n!}$, with $g^{\overline{j}k}$ being the inverse matrix of $g_{k\overline{j}}$.

What have I tried: I tried calculating $n=1$ scenario, which reduces to $T=g^{\overline{1}1}T_{\overline{1}1}g_{\overline{1}1}dz_1d\overline{z_1}$.

However, when I tried to go to $n=2$, I have $LHS=(-T_{\overline{1}2}g_{2\overline{1}}-T_{2\overline{1}}g_{1\overline{2}}+T_{1\overline{1}}g_{2\overline{2}}+T_{2\overline{2}}g_{1\overline{1}})dz_1\wedge d\overline{z_1}\wedge dz_2\wedge d\overline{z_2}$ and $RHS=\frac{1}{2}(g^{1\overline{2}}T_{\overline{2}1}+g^{2\overline{1}}T_{\overline{1}2}+g^{1\overline{1}}T_{\overline{1}1}+g^{2\overline{2}}T_{\overline{2}2})det(g_{i\overline{j}})dz_1\wedge d\overline{z_1}\wedge dz_2\wedge d\overline{z_2}$, which I can't manage to fit together.

Now that I couldn't fit these together, I began to doubt whether the formula is true in general for Hermitian forms. Do we need the form $\omega$ to be Kahler?

Help?

Comment: First, you have a typo. It should be $\omega^{n-1}$. If this is just linear algebra, how can closedness of $\omega$ be remotely relevant? Your summation convention looks suspicious — ordinarily we sum lower $k\bar k$ and either $^k\,_k$ or $^{\bar k}\,_{\bar k}$. And my personal preference would be to use wedge products everywhere, since hermitian metrics are often written without the tensor product.

Comment: You are right, it should be $\omega^{n-1}$. I guess in class we assumed $\omega$ to be kahler, and I think I have seen somewhere that under a proper change of basis Kahler forms have nice local representations. And I followed my prof in class on the summation convention. I guess this isn't the standard one because he saves the upper indices for the inverse matrix.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't quite following you. So have you used the formula for the inverse matrix?

Comment: It might be wise ultimately to do the computation in a unitary coframe.

Comment: I tried the inverse matrix formula just now, but I get LHS$=(T_{1\overline{2}}g^{1\overline{2}}+T_{2\overline{1}}g^{2\overline{1}}+T_{1\overline{1}}g^{1\overline{1}}+T_{2\overline{2}}g^{2\overline{2}})det(g_{i\overline{j}})dz_1\wedge d\overline{z_1}\wedge dz_2\wedge d\overline{z_2}$, which lacks a $\frac{1}{2}$ from the RHS?

Comment: ok, i think i get the $\omega^n$ part wrong, $\omega^n$ should be $n!det(g_{i\overline{j}}dz_1\wedge d\overline{z_1}\wedge ...\wedge dz_n\wedge d\overline{z_n}$, so you are right prof Ted

Comment: Do you want to maybe elaborate a bit on the unitary coframe part?

Comment: This amounts to diagonalizing the $g_{i\bar j}$ matrix and writing $\omega = \frac{\sqrt{-1}}2\sum \phi_j\wedge\bar\phi_j$. Then write $T = \sum a_{i\bar j}\phi_i\wedge\bar\phi_j$. I typically have a factor of $\sqrt{-1}/2$ in my Kähler form, so that the remaining matrix of coefficients is positive-definite hermitian. Think of $dz\wedge d\bar z = -2i\,dx\wedge dy$ in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: I would avoid coordinates at first and notice that you want to calculate $T \wedge *\omega = \langle T, \omega \rangle \omega^n / n!$, which should be easier to get a hold on. In terms of matrices in local coordinates that inner product is $\langle A, B \rangle = tr(A \omega^{-1} \overline B \omega^{-1})$, which seems to simplify to what you want.